# Compilation Error in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In my application i am using youtubevide (www.aspnet-video.com). I installed and write the code. when i run this application it is showing like this.....

Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'ASPNetVideo.WindowsMedia' exists in both 'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\youtubevideo\fe0d5a9d\4d87ccb0\assembly\dl3\690f1934\002677f1_a2eec901\ASPNetVideo.NET3.DLL' and 'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\youtubevideo\fe0d5a9d\4d87ccb0\assembly\dl3\b377a6f8\17e0b64d_33fcca01\ASPNetVideo.NET2.DLL'

Source Error:

Line 11:     
Line 12:       
Line 13:           
Line 14:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have included tho different assemblies defining the same class. Have a look at your project references.

Comment: thank you i added two dll it is working fine now Mr. Adrian grigore